# ¿Por qué el mineral "alofana" aparece en algunos lugares como "alófana"?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, acentuación, terminología, ciencia

El mineral *alofana* aparece cómo "alófana" en los procesadores de palabra.

Esto es un error: debe ir sin acento (*alofana*) como los nombres de otros minerales ej. naufana.

Alófana acentuado suena como la raíz "halo", o como si se tratara de phonos. ¿Es acaso este error un colombianismo o, más en general, por qué se comete tanto este error?

Comment: he visto en google en ambas formas, pero si el original es *alofana* puede ser por analogía con la palabra *alófono/a* que sí lleva tilde.

Comment: Veo referencias con tilde incluso en el libro _Química de suelos, énfasis en suelos de América Latina_.

Comment: http://dle.rae.es/?id=23CsjcY

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es por analogía a las palabras (much más comúnes) que terminan in [*‒́fono, na*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ICOA9IM) (de griego antiguo -φωνος (*-phōnos*)). Aparte de *interfono* (de fr. *interphone*) y *fono* si mismo, todas estas palabras son esdrujulas, incluso el muy similar *alófona*:

- `esdrujula` *aerófona, áfona, alófona, anglófona, audífono, audiófono, citófono, datáfono, dictáfono, francófona, gramófono, hidrófono, homófona, isófona, laringófono, magnetófono, megáfono, mensáfono, micrófono, perífono, polífona, radioteléfono, saxófono, teléfono, vibráfono, videoteléfono, xilófono*
- `llana` *fono, interfono*

O puede ser por confusión con las otras palabras en *-fana*, que son una mezcla de esdrujulas y llanas:

- `esdrujula` *aljáfana, búfana, diáfana, hidrófana, huérfana*
- `llana` *alfana, ferreñafana, profana, tarafana, [agua] tofana, ufana*